# Existence of holomorphic function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is there a holomorphic function that satisfies $f(\frac{1}{n})=n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

I was thinking about applying the Identity Theorem to show that the function must be $f(z)=\frac{\sin{z}}{z}$ for $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$ but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Are you even asked to prove that the function "must be" $f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin z}{z}&z\ne 0\\1&z=0\end{cases}$? It looks more like a question to *find* a holomorphic function, i.e. about *existence* rather than *uniqueness*. Because, for existence, it is enough to say $\frac{1}{n}\ne 0$ for all $n$, so $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, and to prove/check that $f(z)$ is indeed holomorphic.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Perhaps, OP does not know that this function is analytic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a limit point $0$. and $f(\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n})$ where $g=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\\ 0,\,z=0\end{cases}$. Hence by the identity theorem $f(z)=g(z)$ .

More explicitly,

Let $g=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,,z\neq 0\\ 0\,,z=0\end{cases}$. Then we have that $g$ is holomorphic and by the problem $(f-g)(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all natural numbers $n$.

So as $f$ is holomorphic, $f-g$ is holomorphic and must have a zero of some order at $z=0$ . Say it is not the $0$ function . Then it must have a zero of some finite order $m$.

Then $(f-g)(z)= a_{m}z^{m}(1+h(z))$ where $h(z)$ is some holomorphic function such that $h(z)\xrightarrow{z\to 0} 0$ and $a_{m}\neq 0$ .

Then we have that $(f-g)(\frac{1}{n})=a_{m}\frac{1}{n^{m}}(1+h(\frac{1}{n}))$ .

By assumption $(f-g)(\frac{1}{n})=0$ . Hence $(1+h(\frac{1}{n}))=0$ as $a_{m}\frac{1}{n^{m}}\neq 0$.

But this gives a contradiction as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+h(\frac{1}{n}))=0\implies\,1=0$.

Hence $(f-g)$ must be the $0$ function.

Comment: Why is the identity theorem needed to prove the existence of $f$. You define $f$ directly.

Comment: Why at all we need to "prove" the existence of f? . f is already given to us. We are defining $g$ and applying identity theorem on $f-g$ which vanish at $\frac{1}{n}$ which has a limit point $0$ in the domain.

Comment: That is a  proof of uniqueness. OP perhaps does  not know that  the function I have defined in my answer is an analytic function and that is what we are supposed to explain.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Perhaps I misunderstood but I mainly read the line that the op wanted to show that the function "must be $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ and op wanted to apply identity theorem to prove it. I figured that since the op guessed the function correctly, op wouldn't have had any trouble proving that it is holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Such a function does exist. If $f(z)=\frac {\sin z } z$ for $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$ then $f$ is an entire function with power series expansion $1-\frac {z^{2}} {3!} +\frac {z^{4}} {5!}-\cdots$ and it does satisfy the given property.